# Как сделать автозамену разрывов строки на теги для RSS фида в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss, acf

Такая проблема — клиент размещает публикуемый контент формата инфоблога на страницах через плагин Advanced Custom Fields (ACF), вместо постов. Не спрашивайте почему — так сделал прошлый подрядчик. Возникла необходимость этот контент вытащить в RSS feed для скармливания другому сервису. Реализовано через код:

```
add_filter( 'xmlsf_news_post_types', 'my_news_post_types', 11 );

function fields_in_feed($content) {  
    if(is_feed()) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $output .= '<p>' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'sections_0_post-content', true) . '</p>';  
        $output .= '<p>' . get_sub_field($post_id, 'sections_0_post-links', true) . '</p>';
        $content = $content.$output;  
    }  
    return $content;  
}  
add_filter('the_content','fields_in_feed');
```

Но возникла такая проблема — контент тянется без разметки параграфов тегом p, а двойным разрывом строки. Есть только внешние теги из кода
Соответственно вопрос — как сделать автозамену в контенте при вызове с разрывов на

```
 </p><p>
```

Comment: Смотрите документацию по функции wp_autop()

Comment: Сделать фильтр контента autop приоритетнее.